# Should I use a REST API, or Socket.io for a Geolocation App?

Tags: node.js, rest, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I need to track moving cars.

Should I post the location every time the location changes, and send it over the socket?

Or should make a REST API and post the location (from the tracked device) and check it (with the tracker device) every 10 seconds, regardless if the location changed or not?

(The App is being made with React Native)

Comment: Both can work. Which scales better?

Answer (score 3):

Building HTTP requests by frequent updates requires more resources then sending messages through websocket. Keeping websocket connections open by a lot of users requires more resources than using HTTP. In my opinion the answer depends on the user count, the update frequency, whether you apply the REST constraints (no server side session) and which version of HTTP you use (HTTP2 is more efficient than HTTP1.1 as far as I know). I don't think this is something we can tell you without measurements.

The same is true if you want to push data from the server to the client. If you do it frequently and the update must be almost immediate, then websocket is probably a better choice than polling. If you do the rarely and the delay (polling frequency) can be a few minutes, then polling might be better.

Note that I am not an expert of load scaling, this is just a layman's logic.

Comment: I understand. The update has to be at least every 5-10 seconds. The App will start with ~300 users. I am more inclined to sockets I might need them on other parts of the App, for example to notify the client when the relevant car starts moving so the client starts asking for location. The question is also which method is easier to maintain, code-wise.

Comment: @Emilios1995 That means 30-60 small request per second. I don't think you will have issues with either solutions, any average server should be able to handle this traffic easily. I think it is easier to maintain the websocket, but it is not much of an effort to maintain the HTTP version either. If you don't like polling, you can use SSE instead. I am currently reading about HTTP 2, which appears to support pushing natively. I suggest you to wait for other, more experienced answers, maybe they will contains aspects I don't know of.

Comment: @Emilios1995 If you decide to use HTTP, I don't think you need REST for this. There is no need for hyperlinks and you won't have multiple 3rd party clients and probably the API won't change either in time, so you don't need to update the clients because of it. In other terms you don't need the flexibility of the uniform interface constraint. Ofc. you can use a few REST constraints, like the stateless constraint, and probably plain JSON, but this is just a simple webapplication, which does not change rapidly, so I don't think you don't need more than that.

Comment: @Emilios1995 - as said before, for small deployments and low-frequency updates basically anything works. I'd suggest going with WebSockets since this is the approach which scales better in the long term.

Comment: @gzost You should add an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 3):

I would use WebSockets. For small deployments and low-frequency updates basically anything works, but with WebSockets you have technology that scales better in the long term. (And no, I would not consider this premature optimization, since the choice of technology here does not mean unnecessary initial overhead.)

Shameless plug: If you're using WebSocket, you could take a look at Crossbar.io - http://crossbar.io, or WAMP (http://wamp-proto.org) in general, which provides messaging mechanisms on top of WebSocket and should work well for you use case. I work for the company which is at the core of this, but it's open source software.